# How to store .mp3 file into Core Data?

Tags: core-data

I found this code to save the file on disk:

```
char *saves = "abcd";
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:saves length:4]; 
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile"];
[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

I am new to Core Data. I want to store MP3 files using it. First I want to download it from web URL, then save it in core data.

Comment: It's not a good idea to store binary files in CoreData. Store enough information in CoreData to retrieve the file from the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the files in the application documents directory (perhaps create a "music" subfolder), and store a reference to those files in Core Data. Ensure that these file are named uniquely ([NSUUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/) may be useful) and that you don't store the path to the file on your managed object, [since this is not guaranteed to be the same next time the application runs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html).